# How to change text in a page by utilizing a custom user id?

Tags: plugins, php, scripts

I am looking for a way to change select text within the homepage on a particular site, utilizing a custom user id. I would like to be able to have multiple user id's for the same website without creating multiple subdomains or a seperate site.

**------------------------------------------------------------------------**

**Example:**

**1. Orignal Website:**
**exampledomain.com**

Original Text, (On Hompepage), reads as follows:

"**Jebs** Construction offers the highest quality Construction services to residential and commercial clients in the **Miami** area."

**-----------------------------------------------------------------**

**2. exampledomain.com?id=123**

User Id = 123 would change the original, "**Jeb's**" text to what you see below.

"**Hillary's** Construction offers the highest quality Construction services to residential and commercial clients in the **Washington D.C.** area."

**------------------------------------------------------------------------**

**3. exampledomain.com?id=9999**

User Id = 9999 would change the original, "**Jeb's**" text to what you see below.

"**Bernie's** Construction offers the highest quality Construction services to residential and commercial clients in the **Burlington** area."

**------------------------------------------------------------------------**

**4. exampledomain.com?id=47679**

User Id = 47679 would change the original, "**Jeb's**" text to what you see below.

"**Donald's** Construction offers the highest quality Construction services to residential and commercial clients in the **New York** area."

**--------------------------------------------------------------------**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a function like so:

```
function construction_intro( $id = '', $echo = true ){

    $id = absint( $id );

    switch ($id) {
        case 123 :
            $name = "Hillary's";
            $location = "Washington D.C.";
            break;
        case 9999 :
            $name = "Bernie's";
            $location = "Burlington";
            break;
        case 47679 :
            $name = "Donald's";
            $location = "New York";
            break;
        default:
           $name = "Jeb's";
           $location = 'Miami';
    }

    $text = sprintf( __( '%1$s Construction offers the highest quality Construction services to residential and commercial clients in the %2$s area.' ),
        $name,
        $location    
    );

    if( $echo ) {
        echo $text;
    } else {
        return $text;
    }
}
```

And then in your homepage you could call like:

```
<div id="intro">
    <p>
    <?php 
        $id = ( ! empty( $_GET['id'] ) ) ? $_GET['id'] : 0 ;
        construction_intro( $id );
    ?>
    </p>
</div>
```